# Как отбросить все элементы, в которых нет хотя бы одного слова

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача состоит в том, чтобы отбросить все строки, в которых нет хотя бы одного слова из строки. Например:

Есть строка: `"system of a down"`
Перебираю массив строк: `["system down", "system of", "moscow never sleeps"]`
Нужно отбросить те строки из массива и итерироваться только по тем, которые содержат хотя бы одно слово из начальной строки (в данном случае moscow never sleeps не попадает)

Делать это нужно быстро, раньше я перебирал каждую строку и проверял на наличие хотя бы одного слова, но это, мне подсказали, неэффективно.
Я сижу уже второй час и никакой код в голову не приходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Первую строку разбиваете на слова и заносите их в set. Идя массиву строк так же разбиваете их на слова и проверяете наличие каждого встреченного слова в set (с помощью in).

Comment: Рассмотрите встроенную python библиотеку `re`

Comment: @Mike можно проще. начальную строку загнать в `set`, так же делать с каждой строкой в массиве. потом просто пересекать множества через операнд `&`. если получилось не пустое - значит есть совпадение

Comment: @Mike так у меня это же: line = ```stdin.readline().rsplit(); for s in strings: if len(set(line) & set(s)) > 0: ...```

Comment: @finally Это не проще, тут вопрос про эффективность. Создание нового объекта set и заполнение его всеми словами строки занимает время и требует дополнительную память. А когда перебираешь слова после split (не знаю, есть ли итератор на подобии split ?) можно остановиться сразу после первого найденного слова и не анализировать остальные

Comment: @headswillroll но вы же свой код не привели в вопросе, как я мог догадаться как у вас написано ? И у вас на каждом шагу цикла создается новый set из line (А надо один раз перед циклом его создать и дальше пользоваться), плюс к этому создается set из s, включающий все слова, в то время как например при сравнении по отдельным словам вы бы для первого случая увидели system и сразу бы признали строку подходящей и перешли к проверке следующего элемента

Comment: @Mike спасибо, сейчас попробую оптимизировать

Comment: Свой код в вопросе приведите, чтобы не нарушать правила сайта, и ваш вопрос не был закрыт

Comment: Нужно смотреть какие там примеры. Может там есть очень длинные фразы, где сразу встречается нужное слово. Тогда эффективнее идти циклом по словам и досрочно прекращать цикл если встретилось нужное слово из другого списка и это будет эффективно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я решил добавлять каждое новое слово в словарь, а в словарь со словом документы, в которых оно встретилось. То есть результирующий словарь вида `{слово: {документ: сколько раз встретилось}}`. Таким образом решение сильно ускорилось

Answer (score 0):

с использованием модуля re может получиться примерно так:

```
from re import search

s = "system of a down"
l = ["system down", "system of", "moscow never sleeps"]

res = list(filter(lambda m: search(fr'{"|".join(s.split())}', m), l))

print(res)  # ['system down', 'system of']
```

Comment: опередил ;)))))